# To set date as min and max values for jquery slider

Tags: jquery

I have to use the date as a min and max to set the values for the JQuery slider.
Here is  my code:

```
 $( "#slider" ).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 1000,
            steps:10,
            values: [ 0, 1000 ],
            change: function( event,ui ) {
             var low = ui.values[0];
             var high = ui.values[1];
             $("#slider").slider("refresh");
           console.log("begin:"+low+"high"+high);

            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You need show some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not been particularly descriptive about exactly what you're after, but I've done something before with dates, a bit like this...

```
    var mindate = new Date('2010-01-01').getTime() / 1000;
    var maxdate = new Date('2020-01-01').getTime() / 1000;
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: mindate,
      max: maxdate,
      step: 86400,
      values: [ mindate, maxdate ]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your `min` and `max` as timestamp and `step` to be seconds count how much you want to increment date.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var minDate = new Date('2016-12-31');
  var maxDate = new Date('2017-12-31');

  $("#slider").slider({
    min: minDate.getTime(),
    max: maxDate.getTime(),
    step: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000, // 1 day
    slide: function(e, ui) {
      var currentDate = new Date(ui.value);
      $('#now').text(currentDate.toDateString());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<span id="now"></span>
```